# ContentProvider or Singleton approach to Android database?

Tags: android, singleton, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite

I see people advocating both of these approaches when dealing with Android SQLite database. I personally prefer Singleton database locking pattern, but new development practices suggest to drop out Singleton pattern.

And now I am confused whether to continue as I am used to or to start using something "new & better".

Which approach it future-proof? Is Singleton approach so bad that it will be abandoned in the future?

Comment: "new development practices suggest to drop out Singleton pattern" -- citation, please.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, cannot provide citation but have read it number of times in the last year or so. Now, I can't remember if I read it on blogs or some more official webpages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As part of good SOLID coding practices, Singletons are generally discouraged.
Singletons become a little bit magic, in that anywhere in your code, you can just pull down a dependency and access it, seemingly from nowhere.

This creates a high level of coupling in the codebase, making it more difficult to change, as well as making it extremely difficult to test.

Patterns like ContentProvider, on the other hand, encourage coding to interfaces and abstractions, which when used carefully reduces coupling, and enables provider instances to be more easily substituted - which is great both for flexibility of the code as well as testability of the code.

Of course, this is not to say that Singletons don't have a place at all - certainly there are situations where it doesn't make sense to not use a Singleton, but where they can be avoided, it's best to avoid them.

If by 'future-proof' you mean 'more flexible and amenable to change', then I would suggest the ContentProvider pattern is the way to go.

Comment: "anywhere in your code, you can just pull down a dependency and access it, seemingly from nowhere" -- the same can be said for a `ContentProvider`. "Patterns like ContentProvider, on the other hand, encourage coding to interfaces" -- `ContentProvider` specifically prevents coding to interfaces, at least in the literal Java definition of the term. `ContentProvider` helps to enforce coding to *abstractions*, which has its pros and its cons.